# XAML Designer Crashes with Self-Registering ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, designer

The XAML designer crashes visual studio 2010 if the view model that is set as the Data Context registers itself in a static class.

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="CTL.Editor.View.EditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:editor="clr-namespace:CTL.Editor.ViewModel.Editor"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <editor:EditorWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public EditorWindowViewModel()
{
    ApplicationViewModel.EditorWindows.Add(this);
}

~EditorWindowViewModel()
{
    ApplicationViewModel.EditorWindows.Remove(this);
}
```

Is there any way around this? Maybe a # directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those seeking a bit more detail than Postlagerkarte's answer:

A way to use IsInDesignMode that is MVVM-friendly is shown below.

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
{
    ....
}
```

My issue was caused by the fact that ApplicationViewModel's constructor what loading a config file and apparently Visual Studio didn't like that, didn't find the file or didn't search for the file in the right place when it was running my code.

What I ended up doing was:

```
public static bool DesignMode
{
    get { return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()); }
}

static ApplicationViewModel()
{
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        Configuration = Configuration.LoadConfigurationDocument();
    }
}
```

Note: There is a Configuration static member on ApplicationViewModel and a Configuration class which loads the config.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to supress execution while in design mode. Just wrap your code in an if statement: `if(!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)`

However it is often a good idea to find the root cause of the problem by debugging the designer exception. [Here](http://www.jayway.com/2013/12/25/visual-studio-2013-and-blend-design-time-exception-debugging/) is an good article that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, That's just what I was looking for. I'm planning on investigating the code a little more before resorting to it but at least there is some sort of option.

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by calling .Add() on a List in a static class (the list is being initialised).